# What is the format for the Directory.users().list().setQuery method?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) states:

> Query string for prefix matching searches. Should be of the form "key":"value" where key can be "email", "firstName" or "lastName".

I've tried:

`directory.users().list().setQuery("email:" + email).execute()`

`directory.users().list().setQuery("\"email\":\"" + email + "\"").execute()`

`directory.users().list().setQuery("email:\"" + email + "\"").execute()`

They all return a 400 : Bad Request response. How do I properly filter on the email address? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the list API supports only prefix queries, please refer to the documentation for query parameter [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list).

Try with query as "email:someEmail@someDomain.com*" -> Note the asterisk at the end.

Comment: I swear there was no mention of an asterisk earlier, but I'll try this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the way to *get* a user by email address.

```
directory.users().get(userKey=email).execute()
```

Code to *search* for a user by email address *should* be something like

```
directory.users().list(query='email:emily@example.com').execute()
```

but this doesn't work. I suspect a bug in [Google's API docs](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/admin/directory_v1/python/latest/admin_directory_v1.users.html#list), or possibly in the actual implementation.

Comment: Good to know I'm not crazy. Thought I was misunderstanding the docs, but a .list() query like that does return error 400. I can get the current job done with .get() but how annoying. Also amazing that this bug is currently at least two years old!

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will point you in the right direction:

```
    var listReq = service.Users.List();
            listReq.Domain = domain;
        Users results = listReq.Execute();
```