# How do you search users in the Google admin sdk api using custom queries?

Tags: java, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-query-language

I am attempting to pull users who have suspended email accounts from one of my company domains. Since we have more than one domain i realize i will need to use custom queries to do this. However, if you look below whenever i run my code, i am give a "400 Bad request" exception. Can someone please help me out over here? Below you can see my code:

```
    public void checkSuspended() throws IOException, NullPointerException, GeneralSecurityException { 

try { 

    Directory directory = GCAuthentication.getDirectoryService("xxxxx", "xxxxxx.p12", "xxxxxxx"); 
//  System.out.println("1"); 
    Directory.Users.List list = directory.users().list(); 
//  System.out.println("2");
    list.setQuery("GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=xxxxxxxx.ca&query=email:xxxxxxxxx");
//  System.out.println("3");
    com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.Users user = list.execute(); 
//  System.out.println(user); 
    }

catch (NullPointerException e){ 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (GeneralSecurityException e ){ 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Please note that my getDirectoryService method is not causing an error here as i already have tested this out.

Here is the exception i am getting:

```
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Bad Request",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Bad Request"
}
    at     com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
at com.brookfieldres.library.test.ExtractionTest.checkSuspended(ExtractionTest.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Please advise what i am doing wrong here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[400: Bad Request](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors) is caused by the wrong parameters in your query statement:
`list.setQuery("GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=xxxxxxxx.ca&query=email:xxxxxxxxx");`

Remove `'GET'` from the query statement.

[Additonal Note](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users):

> The query parameters must be URL encoded. For example, the query
>   query=givenName:Jane* is URL encoded as query=givenName%3AJane*.
>   Client libraries handle this URL encoding automatically.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178387/what-is-the-format-for-the-directory-users-list-setquery-method) might help also.

> ```
> directory.users().get(userKey=email).execute()
> ```